# Scala groupBy all elements in the item's list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list of tuples, where the first element is a string and the second is a list of strings.

For example...(ignoring speech marks)

```
val p = List((a, List(x,y,z)), (b, List(x)), (c, List(y,z)))
```

My goal is to group this list into a map with the elements of the nested lists acting as keys.

```
val q = Map(x -> List(a,b), y -> List(a,c), z-> List(a,c))
```

My initial thought was to group by the second elements of p but this assigns the entire lists to the keys.

I'm a beginner to Scala so any advice is appreciated. Should I expect to be able to complete this with higher order functions or would for loops be useful here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone, I will check out the approaches on Monday :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two variants:

```scala
val p = List(("a", List("x","y","z")), ("b", List("x")), ("c", List("y","z")))

// 1. "Transducers"
p.flatMap{ case (k, v) => v.map { _ -> k }  }  // List((x,a), (y,a), (z,a), (x,b), (y,c), (z,c))
  .groupBy(_._1) // Map(z -> List((z,a), (z,c)), y -> List((y,a), (y,c)), x -> List((x,a), (x,b)))
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2)) // Map(z -> List(a, c), y -> List(a, c), x -> List(a, b))

// 2. For-loop
var res = Map[String, List[String]]()

for ( (k, vs) <- p;  v <- vs) {
  res += v -> k :: res.getOrElse(v, List())
}

res  // Map(x -> List(b, a), y -> List(c, a), z -> List(c, a))

// Note, values of `res` are inverted, 
// because the efficient "cons" operator (::) was used to add values to the lists
// you can revert the lists afterwards as this:

res.mapValues(_.reverse) // Map(x -> List(a, b), y -> List(a, c), z -> List(a, c))
```

Second variant is more performant, because no intermediate collections are created, but it also could be considered "less idiomatic", as mutable variable `res` is used. However, it's totally fine to use mutable approach inside a private method.

---

UPD. Per @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez's suggestions:

In (1), since scala 2.13,  `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` can be replaced by `groupMap`, so the whole chain becomes:

```scala
p.flatMap{ case (k, v) => v.map { _ -> k }  }
   .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```

Another functional variant without intermediate collections can be achieved using `foldLeft`:

```scala
p.foldLeft(Map[String, List[String]]()) {
  case (acc, (k, vs)) =>
    vs.foldLeft(acc) { (acc1, v) =>
      acc1 + (v -> (k :: acc1.getOrElse(v, List())))
    }
}
```

Or slightly more efficiently with `updatedWith` (scala 2.13):

```scala
p.foldLeft(Map[String, List[String]]()) {
  case (acc, (k, vs)) =>
    vs.foldLeft(acc) { (acc1, v) =>
      acc1.updatedWith(v) {
        case Some(list) => Some(k :: list)
        case None       => Some(List(k))
      }
    }
}
```

... or same thing slightly shorter:

```scala
p.foldLeft(Map[String, List[String]]()) {
  case (acc, (k, vs)) =>
    vs.foldLeft(acc) { (acc1, v) =>
      acc1.updatedWith(v)(_.map(k :: _).orElse(Some(List(k))))
    }
}
```

Overall, I'd suggest either using `foldLeft` variant (most performant and functional), or the first, `groupMap` variant (shorter, and arguably more readable, but less performant), depending on your goals.

Comment: You could use `groupMap` in the first one to reduce some intermediate collection. - Anyways, the second one can be made faster and more functional by using an `Iterator` and `foldLeft` and using `updateWith` to simplify the logic.

Comment: Something like this: _(it may have typos)_ `p.iterator.flatMap { case (k, vs) => vs.Iterator.map(v => v -> k) }.foldLeft(Map.empty[V, List[K])) { case (acc, (v, k)) => acc.updatedWith(key = v) { case Some(list) => Some(k :: list) case None => Some(Nil) } }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thank you, I've updated my answer, incorporating your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your input list `p` is one step away from being a `Map`. From there all you need is a general purpose Map inverter.

```
import scala.collection.generic.IsIterableOnce
import scala.collection.Factory

// from Map[K,C[V]] to Map[V,C[K]] (Scala 2.13.x)
implicit class MapInverter[K,V,C[_]](m: Map[K,C[V]]) {
  def invert(implicit iio: IsIterableOnce[C[V]] {type A = V}
                    , fac: Factory[K,C[K]]): Map[V,C[K]] =
    m.foldLeft(Map.empty[V, List[K]]) {
      case (acc, (k, vs)) =>
        iio(vs).iterator.foldLeft(acc) {
          case (a, v) =>
            a + (v -> (k::a.getOrElse(v,Nil)))
        }
    }.map{case (k,v) => k -> v.to(fac)}
}
```

usage:

```
val p = List(("a", List("x","y","z")), ("b", List("x")), ("c", List("y","z")))
val q = p.toMap.invert
//Map(x -> List(b, a), y -> List(c, a), z -> List(c, a))
```